# How to check whether a string having asterisk (*) in between is present in a file or not using grep?

Tags: bash, grep

I have a SQL file that contains multiple queries. I need to find whether a query stored in a variable is present in this file or not.

What I have tried:

```
query="select *from abc;"
if grep -q "$query" sqlFile.sql 
then
   echo "duplicate $query"
fi
```

This works for all queries except those which have an asterisk (`*`) in the query.

Comment: Remove the `$` from the query variable first, its an incorrect syntax

Comment: use `fgrep` instead of `grep`  or use `grep -F`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make your search strings to be literal strings rather than allowing to be regexp characters, use the `-F` flag,

```
query="select *from abc;"

if grep -qF "$query" sqlFile.sql ; then 
    echo "duplicate $query"
fi
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked.it was not allowing me to accept this answer .now i am able to do that .

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
query="select \* from abc"                                                     

if grep -q "$query" sqlFile.sql                                                
then                                                                            
        echo "duplicate $query" 
fi
```